# Testing F# async workflows with xUnit.net's Task support

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, f#, workflow, xunit.net

I'm writing F# code and tests in [xUnit 1.9](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2012/01/xunit19.html).

For normal sync stuff, I simply return `unit` and all is well; but now, I'm migrating the sync innards to be `async` workflows.

In other words, my simple AAA is getting explicit `Async` usage pushed out into it as I refactor the system:

```
let [<Fact>] ``Can consume using NEventStore InMemory`` () = 
    let store = NesGateway.createInMemory ()

    let finalDirection = playCircuit store |> Async.RunSynchronously // <----- YUCK

    test <@ CounterClockWise = finalDirection @>
```

To remedy this, I want to make the body of the test be `async`. However, to the best of my knowledge, xUnit.net only manages methods returning `Task`-derived types, and hence I need a safe way of having my `async` test body be wrapped suitably for xUnit.net's runner to pick it up and handle it appropriately.

What's the best way to express my above test ?

Comment: Why "yuck"? What's wrong with that code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mausch/8943d1b0f884f88bd8ae

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Cool idea. I thought of Exude when I saw your code before I read your mention. The yuck is referring to the fact that I could have a sync test with explicit `Async` stuff but find that having the test `async` as with your example yields something cleaner (one reason being that the test code is in line with the impl). I do agree that in the degenerate case of a clean AAA that its much of a mauschness whether to sprinkle in an `Async` vs having to switch the test as a whole to `async`. (I do like the idea & look of a lot of Fuchu and the like but 'am not there yet' :)

Comment: On reflection, your first comment is right on the money re my 3 tests - it's not worth the messing. https://github.com/bartelink/FunDomain/blob/cdab0753d05f4cec875abe9435ebec7db65cbdf6/FunDomain.Persistence.NEventStore.Acceptance/EndToEnd.fs and https://github.com/bartelink/FunDomain/blob/cdab0753d05f4cec875abe9435ebec7db65cbdf6/FunDomain.Persistence.EventStore.Acceptance/EndToEnd.fs BTW xUnit v2 has built in parallelization :P Will report back when the codebase becomes more interesting and can consider it then. BTW would love any comments you have on the general codebase before I put it on CR

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As part of xUnit 2.2 Beta 3, @Brad Wilson has done [the necessary to make it work natively directly](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/commit/a2aa665f1b9633e8ec00f549c5df73a0c784a742). Hence one can now simply write:

```
let [<Fact>] ``Can consume NEventStore InMemory`` () = async {
    let store = NesGateway.createInMemory ()

    let! finalDirection = playCircuit store

    test <@ CounterClockWise = finalDirection @> }
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately (to the best of my knowledge [which is not saying a lot, hence the question]), the cleanest that's possible is to use the `Async.StartAsTask <| async` applelation thusly:

```
let [<Fact>] ``Can consume NEventStore InMemory`` () = Async.StartAsTask <| async {
    let store = NesGateway.createInMemory ()

    let! finalDirection = playCircuit store

    test <@ CounterClockWise = finalDirection @> }
```

---

Or, for a little more safety (an async `[Fact]` will not be recognized as sync by xUnit.net if the return type is not [derived from] `Task`) and [arguably] cleanliness (reads better):

```
// Ensure we match the return type xUnit.net is looking for
let toFact computation : Task = Async.StartAsTask computation :> _

let [<Fact>] ``Can play a circuit using GES``() = toFact <| async { 
    use! store = createStore()
    let! finalDirection = playCircuit store
    CounterClockWise =! finalDirection }
```

Comment: Yes, this is much better than the accepted answer, because it doesn't block threads (and cause potential deadlocks).

Comment: @BradWilson unaccepted other answer; leaving this unaccepted too as it would be nice to have some neater direct way not involving a helper

Answer (score 2):

You can also create your own computation expression to encapsulate the `Async.RunSynchronously` call:

```
type AsyncTestBuilder() =
  member this.Bind (v: Async<'a>, c: 'a -> 'b) = v |> Async.RunSynchronously |> c;
  member this.Zero () = ()

let asyncTest = AsyncTestBuilder() 

let [<Fact>] ``Can consume using NEventStore InMemory`` () = asyncTest {
  let store = NesGateway.createInMemory ()

  let! finalDirection = playCircuit store  // <-- use let! instead of let

  test <@ CounterClockWise = finalDirection @> }
```

Comment: On reflection, not sure why I accepted this (except I'm not happy with mine). While it's subjectively nicer than my initial answer there may be value (constraining the levels of trickery one is 'permitted' to inline into a test body), straying away from `AsyncBuilder` for building `async` computations is probably best confined to 'cool trick' territory. Wondering if you've ever gone down this road any distance ? (I tried deriving from `AsyncBuilder` with the aim of constraining the ultimate `return`/`return!` type [only] but it's `sealed` so I gave up and just use a `toFact` helper (see below)

Comment: To be honest, I use Async.RunSynchronously when unit testing async functions. Exactly as in your question. I like being explicit about that.

Comment: I guess you're not doing as mucking about in your tests as much as me then :P

Answer (score 0):

Post F# 6, you can use the in-the-box `task {` expressions

---

[Pre-F# 6, and] Pre xUnit 2.2, you can use a [TaskBuilder](http://fssnip.net/7TE) to yield a `Task<T>` using the same style as `async` :-

```
let [<Fact>] ``Can consume NEventStore InMemory`` () = task {
    let store = NesGateway.createInMemory ()

    let! finalDirection = playCircuit store

    test <@ CounterClockWise = finalDirection @> }
```

Excerpt (don't take it, take [the full source](http://fssnip.net/7TE) as you'll find it relevant for all kinds of `Task`-munging):

```
open System.Threading
open System.Threading.Tasks

[<AbstractClass>]
type AsyncBuilderAbstract() =
    // AsyncBuilder is marked sealed, so we need this wrapper
    member __.Zero() = async.Zero()
    member __.Return t = async.Return t
    member __.ReturnFrom t = async.ReturnFrom t
    member __.Bind(f,g) = async.Bind(f,g)
    member __.Combine(f,g) = async.Combine(f,g)
    member __.Delay f = async.Delay f
    member __.While(c,b) = async.While(c,b)
    member __.For(xs,b) = async.For(xs,b)
    member __.TryWith(b,e) = async.TryWith(b,e)

type TaskBuilder(?ct : CancellationToken) =
    inherit AsyncBuilderAbstract()
    member __.Run f : Task<'T> = Async.StartAsTask(f, ?cancellationToken = ct)

type UntypedTaskBuilder(?ct : CancellationToken) =
    inherit AsyncBuilderAbstract()
    member __.Run f : Task = Async.StartAsTask(f, ?cancellationToken = ct) :> Task

let task = new TaskBuilder()
```