# Implementing C# method returning Task<T> in F#

Tags: c#, f#, async-await, c#-to-f#

I'm creating a type in F# that inherits from a C# class that exposes a method that returns `Task<T>` in C#. I'm trying to work out what'd be the best way to do that in F#

Say my C# looks like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public TextWriter Out { get { return Console.Out; } }

    public virtual Task<SomeEnum> DoStuff() {
        return Task.FromResult(SomeEnum.Foo);
    } 
}

public enum SomeEnum {
    Foo,
    Bar
}
```

My first pass of inheriting that type in F# looks like so:

```
type Bar() =
    inherits Foo()

    override this.DoStuff() =
        this.Out.WriteLineAsync("hey from F#") |> ignore

        System.Threading.Task.FromResult(SomeEnum.Bar)
```

But a) it doesn't feel like it's actually async and b) it just feels not-F#.

So how would I go about inheriting the `Foo` class and implement the `DoStuff` method that expects to return a `Task<T>`?

Comment: Is your actual method really just returning a constant? Because it doesn't make sense to do that in a way that's "actually async". If that is the case, `Task.FromResult()` is the right solution both in C# and F#.

Comment: We can assume that the value to be returned will be based off some logic.

Comment: But is that logic doing any inherently asynchronous work (e.g. accessing the file system or the network)? Or could it take relatively long time (say, more than 50 ms)?

Comment: Yep, file system, network, db, etc could be the async stuff that is done here. The base class also does expose a `TextWriter` to write to the output stream (console, network stream, etc) which is why I used it in my example there.

Comment: [slightly] Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605130/testing-f-async-workflows-with-xunit-nets-task-support

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Async.StartAsTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee821132.aspx):

```
type Bar() =
    inherit Foo()
    override this.DoStuff() =
        async { return SomeEnum.Bar } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

`Async.StartAsTask` takes `Async<T>` as input, and returns a `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

The F# way of doing async is using [asynchronous workflows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx). Unfortunately, [they don't support awaiting non-generic `Task`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8022909/41071). But using one of the workarounds from the above question, your code could look like this:

```
override this.DoStuff() =
    async {
        do! this.Out.WriteLineAsync("hey from F#") |> Async.AwaitVoidTask
        return SomeEnum.Bar
    } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the FSharp way of wrapping over tasks is to use

```
var a = Async.AwaitIAsyncResult(somecsharpreturningtask) |> ignore
```